# How to change a wire frame sphere to solid sphere in opengl

Tags: opengl

When I Am displaying the image it is in wire frame sphere . I would like to change it into a solid filled sphere by ppressing a key from keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );`

to

`glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL );`

when the desired key is triggered.

Unless you are achieving the wireframe effect in another fashion.

**Edit**

In response to your comment, have your tried [gluQuadricDrawStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

`gluQuadricDrawStyle( yourSphere, GLU_FILL );`

Never really used `glu` so not sure if it will solve your issue.

Comment: Actually I have three wire frame spheres which are in circular shape and I created each of the sphere with gluquadsphere(sphere,0.5,32,32). So i need to change these wire frame into solid sphere